# Problems installing imagemagick

Tags: imagemagick, homebrew, refinerycms

Im trying to start my first refinery cms project, and am already having trouble. I am trying to get imagemagick going, and am getting errors. I looked on stackoverflow about changing permissions to my profile, or the directories that have problems, also uninstalling and reinstalling, but so far no luck. I was hoping maybe someone could walk me through fixing this. Thanks so much.

```
 Mac-Pro:local user$ brew install imagemagick
 Error: You must `brew link jpeg' before imagemagick can be installed
 Mac-Pro:local user$ brew link jpeg
 Linking /usr/local/Cellar/jpeg/8d... 
 Error: Could not symlink file: /usr/local/Cellar/jpeg/8d/bin/wrjpgcom
 /usr/local/bin is not writable. You should change its permissions.
```

Comment: It looks like `/usr/local/bin` isn't writeable. Doing `ls -la /usr/local` will tell you the permissions of the `bin` directory (mine belongs to my user, in the `admin` group).

Comment: This is what I am getting when doing ls -la /usr/local    drwxr-xr-x  36 root        admin  1224 Oct 21 14:37 bin

Comment: how do i change it to make it writeable?

Comment: `sudo chown -R yourusename:admin /usr/local/bin`. This recursively changes the contents of `bin` to belong to the user `yourusername` in the group `admin`.

Comment: @Alex, your commment is awesome. Make it an answer, so we can upvote you!

Answer (score 78):

After encouragement, here's my comment to [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13002494/596068) as an answer.

The problem is that the directory Homebrew is trying to use isn't writable by the user running `brew`. To fix this, make the directory writable by that user.

```
sudo chown -R yourusename:admin /usr/local/bin
```

This recursively changes the ownership of all objects inside the `/usr/local/bin` directory to the user called `yourusername`. It assumes that your user is in the OS X administrator group.

If you're not sure of the username of your user, you can run the command `whoami`.

Comment: It might also be worth noting that the Xcode command line tools must be installed, too.

Comment: @JordanThornquest Sure, but [the tools are a prerequisite for Homebrew](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/Installation#requirements). Installing those tools doesn't solve the problem in question.

Comment: `sudo chown -R $(whoami):admin /usr/local`