# gitk: command not found

Tags: git, gitk

Environment: Mac OSX 10.10. When I was trying to use `gitk`, it shows:

```
Coda-2:~ Coda$ gitk
-bash: gitk: command not found
```

I think the reason is the old version of `git`. Here is some information, and I have already typed `brew update`.

```
Coda-2:~ Coda$ git --version
git version 1.9.3 (Apple Git-50)
Coda-2:~ Coda$ brew install git 
Warning: git-2.4.0 already installed, it's just not linked
```

What is this message: `it's just not linked`?

Furthermore, I check the path of `git`:

```
Coda-2:~ Coda$ which git
/usr/bin/git
```

It should be in `/usr/bin/local/git`? How to fix it?

#### UPDATE

I figure it out, thank @TimCastelijns.

`brew doctor` said:

```
Warning: You have unlinked kegs in your Cellar
Leaving kegs unlinked can lead to build-trouble and cause brews that depend on
those kegs to fail to run properly once built. Run `brew link` on these:

    git
```

So, I typed:

```
Coda-2:~ Coda$ brew link git
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/git/2.4.0... 220 symlinks created
```

Then I typed `gitk`, and it worked and the path changed to `/usr/local/bin/git`. However, when I want to check the version of `git`. It still showed the old version, why?

```
Coda-2:~ Coda$ git --version
git version 1.9.3 (Apple Git-50)
```

Comment: *What is it's just not linked?* means if you type `git` it will use the old installation, not the new one

Comment: HaHa! I know now! thank you, I figure it out!

Comment: But, I link the new version and the `gitk` also work, why it still show me an old version of git when I type `which git`

Comment: Use `type`, not `which`.

Comment: sorry,I add the wrong command. I means that I type `git --version` , doesn't it should show `git version 2.4`? But it show me `git version 1.9.3`

Comment: fine, I figure it out and update my answer.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Follow these steps to fix the issue:

1. Check `git` version with `git --version`, and it may show old version.
2. Update Homebrew with `brew update`.
3. Install the latest version of Git from Homebrew with `brew install git`.

   (Note that if anything went wrong with the installation, the `brew doctor` command can be used. In my case, it told me to use `brew link git`.)

I can now use `gitk`.

Comment: Good answer, but you shouldn't use brew with sudo.

Comment: If anyone gets a problem while using `brew link git` (i.e, ownership issues), look into this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26647412/homebrew-could-not-symlink-usr-local-bin-is-not-writable

Comment: Thank you. TLDR version command `brew install git` by itself sufficed for me.

Comment: Why gitx when the question is about gitk?

Comment: If windows go for this solution

Answer (score 82):

I just installed the latest version of git via homebrew on macos.

```
11:28 $ git --version
git version 2.25.0
```

It doesn't seem to have gitk and git gui so I noticed the answer for linux and tried to install the same package `git-gui` via homebrew and it worked.

```
brew install git-gui
```

Found the bug [here](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/39987).

I'm running macos 10.14.5 Mojave.

Comment: It makes sense, git seems not to include the gitk in the standard package anymore.

Comment: It's even mentioned in the caveats after `brew install git` (or `brew info git`) now if you take a moment to read through: ```From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/git.rb
==> Dependencies
Required: gettext ✔, pcre2 ✔
==> Options
--HEAD
 Install HEAD version
==> Caveats
The Tcl/Tk GUIs (e.g. gitk, git-gui) are now in the `git-gui` formula.```

Comment: `brew doctor` didn't find any issues, installing `git-gui` solved it for me. Running Catalina.

Comment: for Mac machine this was easy fix..worked for me

Answer (score 5):

Granted the OP is using Mac, a Linux user will find this link from Google and the accepted solution will not help.

On Linux, use your favourite package manager and install `git-gui`.

On RedHat-based systems, ex CentOS, do:

`yum install -y git-gui`

which will install the `gitk` dependency.

Done.