# gitk not found on OSX Apple Git-55

Tags: git, macos, gitk

I am using git on OSX.

`git --version` returns

```
git version 2.3.2 (Apple Git-55)
```

From Googling, it seems this version should include `gitk`. But when I run the command, I get command not found.

```
gitk
bash: gitk: command not found
```

Why is this, and how can I get gitk on OSX? I am not using homebrew.

Comment: It's very likely Apple stripped gitk from their included git (for reasons unknown, but one can wager the gitk GUI doesn't really suit the overall Apple theme; and by default git would be run through XCode). It's also what [this question (and answer)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17582685/install-gitk-on-mac) indicate.

Comment: @Evert I saw that question. I assumed mine was different because I had such a later version (55). I saw somewhere also that version 45 did have gitk. So it looks like perhaps it came and went.

Comment: It appears to have disappeared in [version 50](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30195143/gitk-command-not-found) (if it ever actually was there in 45).

Comment: Btw, no harm in using homebrew and get the latest-greatest on the git end (or other s/w).

Comment: @Evert thanks. I got git from homebrew. I just wasn't sure if there were any changes that would be incompatible.

Comment: I just brew installed git and got gitk. So far no issues...

Comment: @AdrianLynch yes, I did that after this post went nowhere and I've been fine too.