# gitk command not found git version: 2.29.1

Tags: git

Recently i updated my git using homebrew, even though it took a long time, it got updated.

Post which gitk results in `command not found`

Tried debugging by following [this stack overflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30195143/gitk-command-not-found) still no use

Have attached a screen shot which show the steps followed from the link mentioned above
[image]

Update 1: post googling someone suggested to install gitk using homebrew and it didn't work either[image]

Comment: tried both - same result

Comment: gitk is a utility that is not related to git itself. You may need to update gitk

Comment: gitk needs tcl/tk and wish; some builds of Git don't include gitk; and I'm not sure what's up with this particular macOS build. The gitk code is included in the Git *source*, though.

Answer (score 2):

Even thought `brew install gitk` didn't work, tried `brew install git-gui` post which `gitk` worked as usual.