# `brew link unbound` returns `/usr/local/sbin is not writable` error

Tags: installation, homebrew

I'm trying to install [unbound](https://www.unbound.net/) using `brew` command.

Here's output for `brew install unbound`:

```
Warning: unbound 1.6.7 is already installed, it's just not linked.
You can use `brew link unbound` to link this version.
```

As you can see, I was asked to use `brew link unbound` to link to unbound 1.6.7.

But I failed to link to it because I got the following error:

```
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/unbound/1.6.7...
Error: Could not symlink sbin/unbound
/usr/local/sbin is not writable.
```

I've the other stackoverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26647412/homebrew-could-not-symlink-usr-local-bin-is-not-writable).

And the answer `sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local` creates the following error:

```
chown: /usr/local: Operation not permitted
```

I'm using macOS High Sierra Version 10.13.2.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following commands solved my problem.

```
sudo mkdir /usr/local/sbin
sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local
brew link unbound
```

Comment: I think you should only run `sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/sbin`. There can be security concerns if you completely override ownership for the /usr/local folder itself. I myself don't know all the implications for why /usr/local is always owned by root, and I don't want to break that assumption if I don't have to.

Comment: @AlexanderBird Nope. Must be some protected system folder:
`TimComp:myfolder tim$ sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/sbin
chown: /usr/local/sbin: No such file or directory
TimComp:myfolder tim$ brew link --overwrite unbound
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/unbound/1.10.0... 
Error: Could not symlink sbin/unbound
/usr/local/sbin is not writable.`