# Postgresql 10.4 is already installed, it's just not linked

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, pg

When I run bundle install when installing gems, I receive this:

Could not find gem 'pg (< 2.0, >= 0.18)' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile.

I used brew install postgresl, a common solution on the web, and receive this:

postgresql 10.4 is already installed, it's just not linked. You can use brew link postgresql to link this version.

I run the link command provided by the terminal, and receive this:

Linking /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/10.4...

Error: Could not symlink share/man/man7/ABORT.7 /usr/local/share/man/man7 is not writable.

Any help diagnosing and fixing this issue would be appreciated.

Comment: have you added sudo before the command?

Comment: @Satya Yes, and I receive this message: Running Homebrew as root is extremely dangerous and no longer supported.
As Homebrew does not drop privileges on installation you would be giving all
build scripts full access to your system.

Comment: I'd advise running `brew doctor` and if there are any permission issues you can fix. Also this answer may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26647594/703903