# PHPUnit can't detect PHP 7.3.2

Tags: php, homebrew

I’ve successfully installed PHPUnit, but I am running into some problems. When I try to run it on the command line, I get this message:

> “PHPUnit 8.0.4 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors. This version of

> PHPUnit is supported on PHP 7.2 and PHP 7.3. You are using PHP 7.1.23
>   (/usr/bin/php).”

When I type “php  –v” in the command line, the system verifies that I’m using version 7.1.23 of the language.

When I tried to install PHP 7.3.2, Homebrew gives me the following message:

> “Warning: php 7.3.2 is already installed, it's just not linked You can
>   use `brew link php` to link this version."

When I try to link, it tells me:

> "Linking /usr/local/Cellar/php/7.3.2...  Error: Could not symlink
>   sbin/php-fpm /usr/local/sbin is not writable.”

So PHP 7.3.2 does exist on my system, but PHPUnit is not detecting it. Would you happen to know of any fix for this? Is there a way to switch to 7.3.2, or to perhaps install an earlier release of PHPUnit that’s compatible with PHP 7.1.23?

Thanks in advance for any help you can give.

Comment: It looks like this is a homebrew issue, not a phpunit one - see the error: "Error: Could not symlink sbin/php-fpm /usr/local/sbin is not writable"

Comment: You were on the right track and then you stopped. Fix the `brew link php` issue by setting the correct permissions -- google should help you.

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26647412/homebrew-could-not-symlink-usr-local-bin-is-not-writable

Comment: Thanks, Alex. So based on what I see there, It seems like I'd enter the following sequence of commands: 

"sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(brew --prefix)/*
brew doctor
brew prune
brew link php@7.3"

Does that seem right, or would I just use "sudo chown -R YOUR_COMPUTER_USER_NAME PATH_OF_FILE"?

Comment: Brew doctor shows me the following: 

"Warning: The following directories do not exist:
/usr/local/sbin

You should create these directories and change their ownership to your account.
  sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/sbin
  sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/sbin"

Answer (score -2):

Maybe you should just try with sudo?

`sudo brew link php`

Edit: It's not a good idea. Please ignore.

Comment: Is using `sudo` here the recommended action by `brew`?

Comment: I don't see why not. Otherwise he will need to chown that directory. Isn't that the same?

Comment: I think running `brew doctor` can be a good idea to find out root cause

Comment: `Error: Running Homebrew as root is extremely dangerous and no longer supported. As Homebrew does not drop privileges on installation you would be giving all build scripts full access to your system.`