# Installing Heroku with brew

Tags: heroku, homebrew

So I am trying to learn how to deploy React apps on Heroku. I already have one ready, but I want to take steps carefully and slowly. So first I am trying to install Heroku in my OS machine. Currently, I am using **OS Catalina Version 10.15.1**.

I type this in my terminal `brew tap heroku/brew && brew install heroku`

and get back this.

```
...
==> Tapping heroku/brew
Cloning into '/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/heroku/homebrew-brew'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 10, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (10/10), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (8/8), done.
remote: Total 10 (delta 0), reused 7 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (10/10), done.
Tapped 2 formulae (38 files, 28.6KB).
==> Installing heroku from heroku/brew
==> Installing dependencies for heroku/brew/heroku: heroku/brew/heroku-node
==> Installing heroku/brew/heroku dependency: heroku/brew/heroku-node
==> Downloading https://cli-assets.heroku.com/homebrew/node-12.13.0.tar.xz
######################################################################## 100.0%
Error: The `brew link` step did not complete successfully
The formula built, but is not symlinked into /usr/local
Could not symlink .
/usr/local/opt is not writable.

You can try again using:
  brew link heroku-node
==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/heroku-node/12.13.0: 3 files, 40.3MB, built in 8 seconds
==> Installing heroku/brew/heroku
Error: An exception occurred within a child process:
  RuntimeError: /usr/local/opt/heroku-node not present or broken
Please reinstall heroku/brew/heroku-node. Sorry :(
Theodosioss-MacBook-Pro:aristi theodosiostziomakas$   brew link heroku-node
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/heroku-node/12.13.0... 
Error: Could not symlink .
/usr/local/opt is not writable.
```

Any ideas what's wrong and how to fix it?

Thanks,
Theo.

Comment: `/usr/local/opt is not writable` looks like the key bit to me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Homebrew: Could not symlink, /usr/local/bin is not writable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26647412/homebrew-could-not-symlink-usr-local-bin-is-not-writable)