# Cannot install/link wget on macos

Tags: macos, homebrew

I'm trying to install wget on macOS.

It's not installed already:

```
foo@foo-MacBook-Pro ros2_foxy % wget
zsh: command not found: wget
```

running brew install gives:

```
foo@foo-MacBook-Pro ros2_foxy % brew install wget  
Warning: wget 1.20.3_2 is already installed, it's just not linked
You can use `brew link wget` to link this version.
```

so trying to link:

```
foo@foo-MacBook-Pro ros2_foxy % brew link wget
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/wget/1.20.3_2... 
Error: Could not symlink share/locale/be/LC_MESSAGES/wget.mo
/usr/local/share/locale/be/LC_MESSAGES is not writable.

'''

how to fix this?
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/26647412/735926.

Comment: yeah, folder permission issue. The link above should resolve your issue.