# nano settings are not adopted from nanorc file

Tags: macos, terminal, nano

I have a new Macbook M1 and usually edit files and write short scripts with `nano`. However, I am stuck in default settings, which are of course not really feasible. I created a file `~/.nanorc` and since it didn't work also a file `~/etc/nanorc` with the following content:

```
set linenumbers
set tabsize 4
set tabstospaces
unset mouse
```

Unfortunately, it has no effect. I don't remember, if I faced the same problem when customising `nano` at my old macbook. Can someone help me out here?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was having the same issue after I installed nano using brew (Monterey on M1). It turned out that nano command is by default symlinked to pico editor in `/usr/bin`, see https://ss64.com/osx/pico.html.

You can try checking if that is the case for you by using `which nano`. In my case it was pointing to `/usr/bin/nano` which is actually just symlink to pico (you can check this with `readlink /usr/bin/nano`)

This is probably an issue with homebrew, check this post [Homebrew: Could not symlink, /usr/local/bin is not writable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26647412/homebrew-could-not-symlink-usr-local-bin-is-not-writable)

As a quick fix (to verify if this is actually the case) you can just create a symlink pointing to homebrew installation of nano: `ln -s /opt/homebrew/bin/nano /usr/local/bin/nano`. 
This should open nano instead of pico when using nano command and settings in .nanorc should now also be taken into account.

Answer (score 1):

Seconded Nik's answered above. It worked on my Mac M2(Ventura 13.4).
I had to do extra steps which learnt from here:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/501862/how-can-i-set-the-default-editor-as-nano-on-my-mac

Details:

```
$brew install nano
$sudo ln -s /opt/homebrew/bin/nano /usr/local/bin/nano
```

Put these in .zshrc

```
export EDITOR=/usr/local/bin/nano
export VISUAL="$EDITOR"
```

then restart the terminal,
`$which nano` gives me `/opt/homebrew/bin/nano`. It also reflects setting my in ~/.nanorc.

--

I end up achieving the same without the link, just replace with
`export EDITOR=/opt/homebrew/bin/nano`

(can kill the softlink by
`$sudo unlink /usr/local/bin/nano`)